# Help me identify relevant work regarding convolution

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request, convolution

Some time ago I read (maybe a wikipedia page?) about work regarding a form of a real function presented as sum of convolutions of different order, where "normal" convolution

$$f(x)=\int k(x,x')g(x')dx'$$

is considered as an first order, similar what $f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is to Taylor series. IIRC higher-orders had product of functions, maybe kernels or input functions, within integral. Does anyone perhaps know what this may be?

Comment: What do you mean what it may be? How it behaves or any book or article that derives results about it?

Comment: @mathreadler I mean, any relevant work - papers or books or relevant authors on the subject. When I google "convolution higher order", massive work regarding solving differential equation via convolution just screen what I had in mind. I think "second order" was something along $\int k(x,x',x'')g(x')g(x'')dx'dx''$ but not very sure.

Comment: Oh, search of my browsing history unexpectedly produced what I was after: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_series . But thanks for taking interest in my question, viewers :-)